# Fields recognition after multiline filtering in logstash

Tags: logstash, multiline

I am trying to filter fields in a log file with groups of lines like

```
=================================
BEGIN of purge log
=================================

INF: Verification du lancement du start
INF: Purge du contenu du repertoire des logs archivees a 15j - /users/wtp00/log/archive
INF: Purge du contenu du repertoire tmp a 8j - /users/wtp00/tmp
INF: Purge du contenu du repertoire histo a 8j - /users/wtp00/histo

=================================
END of purge log
=================================
```

I had succeed in treating the INF lines as a message with multiline codec. With the following filter ...

```
filter {
    # Exclude lines with no relevant data
    if ([message] !~ "(^\s*INF:|^\s*$)")  {
        drop {}
    }
    # Treat consecutive lines beginning with INF: as a group
    multiline {
        pattern => "^INF: "
        what => "previous"
    }
    # Delete messages with blank lines
    if ([message] == "")  {
        drop {}
    }
    # Delete \n from messages
    mutate
    {
       gsub => ["message", "\n", ""]
    }

}
```

... with the following result ...

```
{
       "message" => "INF: Verification du lancement du startINF: Purge du contenu du repertoire des logs archivees a 15j - /users/wtp00/log/archiveINF: Purge du contenu du repertoire tmp a 8j - /users/wtp00/tmpINF: Purge du contenu du repertoire histo a 8j - /users/wtp00/histo",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-07-13T15:01:49.442Z",
          "host" => "suse",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ]
}
```

**Now in the message I want to recognize fields (string before - and path after -) for each line, which could be easy to do taking in account that INF: is the beginning of each line.**

In this example the result of field searching for this message should be something like:

```
warning[0] = "Verification du lancement du start"
warning[1] = "Purge du contenu du repertoire des logs archivees a 15j"
warning[2] = "Purge du contenu du repertoire tmp a 8j"
warning[3] = "Purge du contenu du repertoire histo a 8j"

path[0] = ""
path[1] = "/users/wtp00/log/archive"
path[2] = "/users/wtp00/tmp"
path[3] = "/users/wtp00/histo"
```

I have been trying in different ways, and I will keep trying, and I do not know how to do. Any help will be really appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Matching "INF: ... - ..." is easy, but doing is N times is not really part of logstash, unless perhaps you drop to ruby{}.

Comment: Thanks! Well, at last I solved it without Ruby :-)

Answer (score 0):

The key is to make the **grok with field recognition for the different matches BEFORE the multiline**.

The solution is the following one:

```
filter {
    # Exclude lines with no relevant data
    if ([message] !~ "(^\s*INF:|^\s*$)")  {
        drop {}
    }
    # Search warning message and path in messages
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "INF: %{GREEDYDATA:warning} - %{GREEDYDATA:logpath}" ]
        match => [ "message", "INF: %{GREEDYDATA:warning}" ]
        match => [ "message", "^\s*$" ]
    }
    # Add empty logpath field to purge message if not present
    if ![logpath] {
        if ([message] != "") {
            mutate {
                add_field => { "logpath" => "" }
            }
        }
    }
    # Treat consecutive lines beginning with INF: as a group
    multiline {
        pattern => "^INF: "
        what => "previous"
    }
    # Delete \n from messages
    if ([message] == "")  {
        drop {}
    }

}
```

Two important things:

- Do not use "path" as a field name
- Do not add fields to empty lines, dropping them afterwards did not work